# What is a code point and code space?

Tags: character-encoding, character, ascii

I was reading the Wikipedia article on code points, but not sure if I understand correctly.

> For example, the character encoding scheme ASCII comprises 128 code
>   points in the range 0hex to 7Fhex

So is 0hex a code point?

Also could not find anything on code space.

PS. If it's a duplicate please post a link in the comments and I'll remove the question.

Comment: A clearer example is Unicode, where code points don't have a particular byte representation, they're just numbers between 0 and something really big (yes, I'm too lazy to look up the limit). It's not the numbers that are interesting, though, it's the meaning ascribed to them (32dec / 20hex meaning space, for example).

Comment: So 20hex is a code point?

Comment: @VeganSv Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *code point* is a numerical code that refers to a single element/character in a specific coded character set, that sentence means that ASCII has 128 possible symbols (only a part of those will be printable characters) and each one of those has a related numerical code by which it can be identified/addressed, the *code point*.

For an alternative wording, check out [this Joel's post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and [this summary by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/terminology.html) that also introduces the concept of code unit :)

To give you a real world example of what code points are, consider the unicode character [snowman ☃](http://www.charbase.com/2603-unicode-snowman), its code point (with unicode syntax `U+<code point in hex>`) is `U+2603`.

Comment: You should change "encoding" to "character set" to reduce confusion with the specific meaning of an encoding as a mapping of codepoints to bytes.

Comment: I still don't get it, I read the Wikipedia article and didn't understand it (I mean in Unicode they are numbers but in other systems they are not...), that's why I asked here, some real example would be helpful because it sounds all theoretical. Maybe I should research other sources. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomBlodget agree 100%.

Comment: @VeganSv should be more clear now with that example.

Answer (score 3):

The concepts are slightly more abstract than the traditional, pre-Unicode concepts.

Traditionally, a "code space" was more or less synonymous with "character range".  A 7-bit encoding would have a code space from 0 through 127, an 8-bit encoding 0 through 255, a 16-bit encoding 0 through 65535.  Unicode has a code space from 0 through 0x10FFFF, though parts of the code space are unpopulated.

Traditionally, a "code point" was more or less synonymous with "character code".  Unicode abstracts away from the single "character code" mapping to emphasize that there is a more-complex relationship between a set of glyphs and a set of character codes, and that some code points (such as joining modifiers) do not encode individual glyphs as such.  Superficially, U+0020 is still the same character as ASCII SPACE 0x20, but Unicode has a much richer set of well-defined attributes and relationships.

Unicode had to coin new terms for these concepts so as not to overload the traditional terms with extended meanings.  A "code space" is a unique, well-defined concept, which is not exactly the same thing as an (implicitly contiguous, possibly fully populated) character range.  A "code point" is a unique, well-defined concept, which is not exactly the same thing as a "character code" (which isn't even entirely well-defined in the first place; it has multiple ambiguous interpretations).